# How can I use bash variable in awk with regexp?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a file like this (this is sample):

```
71.13.55.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.12|8.8.8.8
81.23.45.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.13|8.8.8.8
61.53.54.62|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.14|8.8.8.8
21.23.51.22|212.152.22.12|71.13.54.12|8.8.8.8
...
```

I have iplist.txt like this:

```
71.13.55.
12.33.23.
8.8.
4.2.
...
```

I need to grep if 3. column starts like in iplist.txt.

Like this:

```
71.13.55.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.12|8.8.8.8
81.23.45.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.13|8.8.8.8
61.53.54.62|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.14|8.8.8.8
```

I tried:

```
for ip in $(cat iplist.txt); do
    awk -v var="$ip" -F '|' '{if ($3 ~ /^$var/) print $0;}' text.txt
done
```

But bash variable does not work in `/^ /` regex block. How can I do that?

Comment: FYI you should properly not use `for i in $(...)`, please see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can use a concatenation of strings for the regular expression, it doesn't have to be a regex block.  You can say:

```
'{if ($3 ~ "^" var) print $0;}'
```

Second, note above that you don't use a `$` with variables inside awk. `$` is only used to refer to fields by number (as in `$3`, or `$somevar` where `somevar` has a field number as its value).

Third, you can do everything in awk in which case you can avoid the shell loop and don't need the var:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {a["^" $0]; next} { for (i in a) if ($3 ~ i) {print;next} }' iplist.txt r.txt
71.13.55.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.12|8.8.8.8
81.23.45.12|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.13|8.8.8.8
61.53.54.62|212.152.22.12|71.13.55.14|8.8.8.8
```

**EDIT**
As rightly pointed out in the comments, the `.`s in the patterns will match any character, not just a literal `.`. Thus we need to escape them before doing the match:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {gsub(/\./,"\\."); a["^" $0]; next} { for (i in a) if ($3 ~ i) print }' iplist.txt r.txt
```

I'm assuming that you only want to output a given line once, even if it matches multiple patterns from iplist.txt. If you want to output a line multiple times for multiple matches (as your version would have done), remove the `next` from `{print;next}`.

Comment: This has a problem because the dot's will match any number in the regex, if you add for instance `21.23.33.22|232.152.22.12|71813.55.56.2|9.9.0.0` it will improperly match.

Comment: `awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {regex=$0; gsub(/\./,"\\.",regex);a["^" regex]; next} { for (i in a) if ($3 ~ i) {print;next} }' iplist.txt r.txt`

Comment: Great point @A.Danischewski, I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `var` directly, instead of in `/^$var/` ( adding `^` to the variable first):

```
awk -v var="^$ip" -F '|' '$3 ~ var' text.txt
```

By the way, the default action for a true condition is to print the current record, so, `{if (test) {print $0}}` can often be contracted to just `test`.

Comment: This works only sometimes, because you are matching the .'s as a regex the dots can complete new ip numbers, try adding `21.23.33.22|232.152.22.12|71813.55.56.2|9.9.0.0` to `text.txt`. If you escape the dot's, it will work: `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for ip in $(< iplist.txt); do     
 awk -vvar="${ip}" -F'|' 'BEGIN{regex="^"var;gsub(/\./,"\\.",regex)}$3 ~ regex{print}' r.txt;  
done`

Comment: @A.Danischewski it would be easier to use the `index` function, I'd say: `index($3, ip) == 1` (assuming GNU awk).

Comment: You can, e.g. `awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR {a[$0];next} { for (i in a) {if (index($3, i)==1){ print;next}}}' iplist.txt r.txt` or `>0` a little shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `bash`, `sed` and `grep`, it's straight forward and I think may be a bit cleaner than `awk` in this case:
`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for ip in $(sed 's/\./\\&/g' iplist.txt); do
    grep "^[^|]*|[^|]*|${ip}" r.txt
done`